# To mock or not to mock the argument of the testing function?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mocking

Let's say i want to test a function `calculateHealth(person)` . And let's say the function take a `person` model argument and return a number from 0% to 100% depending on how healthy the `person` is. Lets say the `person` model is costly to create since it has many properties and sub models which also have many properties. I feel like i should mock the person out and substitute it with a simpler version of a person that only behave enough to test my `calculateHealth()` function. But according to an expert's oppinion (Justin Searls – Please don’t mock me - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Af4M8GMoxi4, at 28:14 ) it is a smell if we **mock** the model value out( for him, it is only ok to mock out dependency but not the model value )

If i have more test like this, it is costly to maintain them if my `person` model change. What is your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

Since `person` is complicated to mock, the test for `calculateHealth()` prove to be difficult. This is a design smell and not the test problem. Instead of passing in a black box `person` , i should define the interface more clearly, and preferably simple to use and to mock/test.